# Swashbuckle UI not displaying Security Scheme Description OAuth2

Tags: asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I'm trying to add a security scheme to my swagger UI page and it's getting added successfully, however, my description is not rendering or being shown at all on the UI page. I want it to display successfully since I will switch this code to be an IOperationFilter and have the description vary by endpoint. For now, though, this is my code for AddSwaggerGen:

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
        {
            options.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo
            {
                Title = "MyAPI",
                Version = "v1"
            });

            options.EnableAnnotations(true);
            options.AddSecurityDefinition("oauth2", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
            {
                Description = "This is my description that's not showing", // I want this to display on the UI
                Type = SecuritySchemeType.OAuth2,
                Flows = new OpenApiOAuthFlows
                {
                    ClientCredentials = new OpenApiOAuthFlow
                    {
                        TokenUrl = new Uri("/token", UriKind.Relative)
                    }
                }
            });

            options.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
            {
                {
                    new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                    {
                        Reference = new OpenApiReference
                        {
                            Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                            Id = "Bearer"
                        },
                        Scheme = "oauth2",
                        Name = "Bearer",
                        In = ParameterLocation.Header
                    },
                    new List<string>()
                }
            });
        });
```

This is my available authorizations that's generated in the UI:
[image]

I would assume my description should go where it's describing scopes like it does for JWT. Am I missing a configuration? I am using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore 5.0.0

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue with Swagger UI:

https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/5230